# How to add a biography to a person in Gramps?

Tags: gramps

I use Gramps to record all my data and would now like to add short biographies to each person. That way I could keep all my information in one place and then write a custom report to generate a document on each person.

Is the best way to use notes, e.g. of type "Report"?

Can I read the tags associated with a note programmatically?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I would create a note for each person. You can give the note a "type" or tag it.

Yes, you can read the tags programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I would use "notes" to create a biography for each person. Then, if you want to, you can create a "detailed ancestral report" for the person in question and as many generations of ancestors as you would like. This form of report lists all the "person notes" that you have written for that individual below their personal information. Thus, if you write a biography as the only note for that person, it will be nicely displayed below their name and birth/marriage/death dates.